# Jest Mock - inserting values into tested file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm having trouble inserting values into the file under test:

```
import device from '../device'

let execute = () => {
  if (device.isAndroid()) {
    return true
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Now for the test file:

```
jest.mock('../device')
import device from '../device'

describe('when the device is Android', () => {
  let device

  beforeEach(() => {
    device = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { 
        isAndroid: () => { return true } 
      }
    })
  })

  it('returns true', () => {
    let results = execute()
    expect(result).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

The test fails and returns `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock `'../device'` with a jest spy and the mock implementation on that:

```
jest.mock('../device', ()=>{return {isAndroid: jest.fn()}})
import device from '../device'

describe('when the device is Android', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    device.isAndroid.mockImplementation(() => true)
  })

  it('returns true', () => {
    let results = execute()
    expect(result).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am getting the following errors: `TypeError: device.isAndroid is not a function - at execute (src/execute.js). TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined - at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/execute.spec.js)` Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, updated my answer to move the mock direct to `isAndroid`

Comment: Firstly, you're a genius!! I got it to work. Please update the above answer and I'll mark it as correct (just want to make sure others don't go astray). First line should be `jest.mock('../device', ()=>{return {isAndroid: jest.fn()}})` Also, remove `let device` as device is already defined by the import statement. That makes it work.